# How to get even values from map and then adding value key to list?

Tags: java, hashmap

Alright, so my problem here right now is that I can get all the words from a list, find the occurrence and then add key and value pairs to map, but since I need to return a list of words which frequency is even, I get stuck. Any help?

```
public static List<String> onlyEvenWordsList(List<String> words) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordsWithCount = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> onlyEvenWords = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        Integer count = wordsWithCount.get(word);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        wordsWithCount.put(word, count + 1);
    }

    for(Integer value: wordsWithCount.values()){
        if(value % 2 == 0){
            ....
            }
    }
    return onlyEvenWords;
}
```

Comment: What's your example input and output?

Comment: instead of iterating over `wordsWithCount.values()` you could be iterating over the entry set `wordsWithCount.entrySet()`. Then you have both key and value available in your loop - Keep your value % 2 check and simply add the key to your list if the value passes your %2 check

Comment: Iterate over map entries rather than just values as you need to filter by value and add the key. `for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: wordsWithCount.entrySet()){if(entry.getValue()%2==0){...add key to onlyEvenWords}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<String> onlyEvenWordsList(List<String> words) {
    Map<String, Integer> wordsWithCount = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> onlyEvenWords = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String word : words) {
        Integer count = wordsWithCount.get(word);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        wordsWithCount.put(word, count + 1);
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: wordsWithCount.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getValue()%2==0){
            onlyEvenWords.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return onlyEvenWords;
}
```

And to print the list in main

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString( onlyEvenWordsList(words).toArray()));
```